# Redshift casting issue to bit

Tags: casting, amazon-redshift, bit

I want to cast a hex string to bit on redshift as follow:
`select 'x827ccb0eea8a706c'::bit(64)`
-> This statement works well.

The problem is that I retrieve the 'x827ccb0eea8a706c' value as a varchar/text.
If the value is casted as a string, I can't convert it to bit:
`select 'x827ccb0eea8a706c'::text::bit(64)`
-> Doesn't work!

How can I solve this issue? How can I cast text to bit?

Comment: When you say 'I retrieve the ... value as a varchar' how are you determining this?  Have you tried a CTAS statement and check the resulting DDL?

Comment: I'm actually trying to execute the following statement:
select ('x'||substr(md5('12345'),1,16))::bit(64)::bigint

When executing this statement, I get the following error:
SQL Error [42846]: ERROR: cannot cast type text to bit

The following statement 'select ('x'||substr(md5('12345'),1,16))' returns 'x827ccb0eea8a706c' as a varchar.

Comment: I think I see the confusion.  Redshift has the function FROM_HEX() to convert to VARBYTE (aka BINARY).  This can then be cast to BIGINT.  SELECT FROM_HEX(substr(md5('12345'),1,16))::BIGINT;  should work.

Comment: Great.  I'm glad you are unblocked.  I'll post this as the answer for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues here:

1. The binary type in Redshift is called BINARY or VARBYTE.
2. A pre-existing function for the conversion of hex text to binary exists in Redshift called FROM_HEX()

The intended query can be written as:

```
SELECT FROM_HEX(substr(md5('12345'),1,16))::BIGINT;
```